# Dynamic Hibernate Query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a method that I use to return a dynamic query. This method is shown below

```
public Query getLastId(String sProvider)
{
       String serviceProvider = sProvider.toLowerCase();     
       String query2 = "SELECT MAX(:serviceProvider.id) " + 
                   " FROM :sProvider :serviceProvider ";

       return em.createQuery(query2)
              .setParameter("sProvider", sProvider)
              .setParameter("serviceProvider", serviceProvider);

}
```

I want this method to return this

```
SELECT MAX(multichoice.id) FROM Multichoice multichoice
```

when I call the method like this

```
getLastId("Multichoice");
```

Please how do I write the query variable to return the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this task you can use Criteria object model and projections to run your query over different types:
Take a look at this [article](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) (15.7. Projections, aggregation and grouping)

here is the code :

```
List results = session.createCriteria(class)
.setProjection( Projections.max("id"))
.list();
```

Then instead of a string you should send a class to your method.